# Format text output of script to html

Tags: html

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
f='/tmp/cases.txt' 
[ -s "$f" ] || printf '%s   |\t%s   |\t%s                    |\n' '#' 'Case Number' 'Date Opened' > "$f"
n=$(cat /tmp/cases.txt | grep 17* |wc -l)
read -p "Enter your SR number: " SR
printf '%d   |\t%d   |\t%s   |\n' "$n" "$SR" "$(date)" >> "$f"
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------" >> "$f"
```

This outputs:

```
#   |   Case Number   | Date Opened                    |
0   |   17416230803   | Wed Mar 29 02:26:24 IST 2017   |
-------------------------------------------------------
1   |   17416230802   | Wed Mar 29 02:32:28 IST 2017   |
-------------------------------------------------------
2   |   17416230801   | Wed Mar 29 02:32:33 IST 2017   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to format this output to a html file. The same way how I see in this text output. 
And if this could generate a link, which I could paste in my browser that would even more cool. I have barely any idea on html so it would be a lot helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to use bash to create an HTML file, and then use HTML syntax from there, injecting the relevant variables. [This link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168866/is-there-a-simple-bash-tool-which-can-quickly-render-basic-html) may help you in that regard.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do exactly. If you want your output to look more or less like in your question, you could probably get away with just wrapping it in `<pre>` and `</pre>` - but then, a text file would do as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ansi2html.sh](https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh) script to generate html file from console output. For example, you can generate the output of `ls -l` as html by:

```
ls -l | ./ansi2html.sh > ls.html
```

Please note you can define the generated file path yourself, which means the "link" is up to you.

p.s. In MacOS, you need to install `gawk` and `gnu-sed` before running `ansi2html.sh`

Comment: I was able to get the right formatting using the ansi2html.sh Thanks.

Comment: This generates a .html file. 
Any way to generate a link kind of deal which I can paste in the browser rather than opening the html file?

Comment: @suhassavkoor do you want to generate link with `file` protocol (such as `file:///Users/test/workspace/ls.html`), or do you want to generate link with `http` protocol (such as `http://localhost:3000/ls.html`)?

Comment: @suhassavkoor is your problem solved? If yes, maybe you can "accept" this answer?